# I never would have guessed

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

Let's say you just met a stranger, and you say:

> 1.I never would have guessed.

To

> 2.I never thought of that.

What is their **meaning** and **difference**.

In a movie I am watching at the moment, the main character(after a short introduction amongst themselves) said **''Really? I never would have guessed''** after meeting another stranger.

why did he just said **''Really? I never would have guessed''** instead of ''**I never thought of that''** is this cultural or something? Thx.

Comment: What was said *before* this line?  It can't be the first thing they've ever said to each other.

Comment: Context is very important, do you have a link to your example?

Comment: Sry for the late reply, I was kinda doin' some impt. stuff also. Anyway, the dialogue of characters in The Postcard Bandit was: bandit(main char.):...hello I'm _____, I'm an engineer here in this art musuem, Japanese: hi I'm _____, nice to meet you, I'm an architect here. Bandit: oh really! I NEVER WOULD HAVE GUESSED THAT... then it continues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "I never would have guessed ..." and "I never would have thought ..." are simply "stock" phrases to express mild surprise, but the actual *degree* depends more on context and intonation.

> Wow!  I **never would have guessed** that he had such an amazing singing voice!
>
> Wow, what a surprise.  I **never would have thought** that John would show up late, to his own birthday party.  Again.

The first sentence indicates polite amazement.  The second sarcastically indicates a complete *lack* of surprise.

"I never thought of that" is somewhat different.  This suggests a lack of information or proper reasoning, which may be surprising.  Again the exact meaning depends entirely on context.

> So you're telling me that you can put peanut butter and jelly on bread to make sandwiches?  Wow, **I never thought of that**.

Tone is everything with this sentence.  It can be honest surprise that the "PBJ" is a thing, or it can be sarcasm since *everyone* knows this.